# React Native - FlatList rendering all of the items in one row repeatedly

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, react-native-flatlist

On the previous screen, you can choose an episode. On this screen, episode ID coming from the previous screen and with this ID, its taking every character ID from API. Characters IDs are slicing from characters URLs. The problem is flatList rendering all of the characters in one row (in one button) repeatedly and stopping at the character that has the last id. How can I solve that?

Episode API: https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/
Character API: https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/

```js
const EpisodeDetailScreen = (props) => {

    const { styles, colors } = useThemedValues(getStyles);
    const loc = useLocalization();

    // character list for flatlist
        const [characterList, setCharacterList] = useState([
    {
        "created": "",
        "episode": [""],
        "gender": "",
        "id": 0,
        "image": "",
        "location": { "name": "", "url": "" },
        "name": "",
        "origin": { "name": "", "url": "" },
        "species": "",
        "status": "",
        "type": "",
        "url": ""
    },
])

    // episode details
    const [episodeDetail, setEpisodeDetail] = useState([])


    // this id come from previous screen
    const { episodeId } = props.route.params

    // details of a chosen episode from the previous screen
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('episode/' + episodeId)
            .then(response => {
                let episodeDetail = response.data
                setEpisodeDetail(episodeDetail) // episode details

                //Getting the IDs of the characters in the section from the last part of the URLs in the incoming data
                // You can see in data example that
                for (var i = 0; i < episodeDetail.characters.length; i++) {
                    const charactersUrlInEpisode = episodeDetail.characters[i]
                    const splittedUrl = charactersUrlInEpisode.split("/");
                    const charactersIdInUrl = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 1]

                    // Extracting character ids and character details from API and throwing them into state
                    takeCharacters(charactersIdInUrl)
                    console.log(charactersIdInUrl) 
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }, [])

    // function that pulls character details from api based on given id
    const takeCharacters = (id) => {
        Axios.get('character/' + id)
            .then(response => {
                let characterDetail = response.data
                setCharacterList([characterDetail])
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    const _renderCharactersItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("character-detail-screen", {
                    characterId: item.id
                });
            }}>
                    <View style={styles.characterButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.characterNameText} numberOfLines={1}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.episodeNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.episodeNameText}>{episodeDetail.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.detailsText}>{loc.t(texts.episode)}{episodeDetail.episode}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailsText}>{loc.t(texts.airDate)} {episodeDetail.air_date}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.characterTitleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.characterTitleText}>{loc.t(texts.characters)}</Text>
            </View>
            <FlatList
                data={characterList}
                renderItem={_renderCharactersItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                style={styles.flatListContainer}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default EpisodeDetailScreen;
```

FlatList style:

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { colorNames } from '../../Theming'
import {Metrics, Fonts} from '../../../StylingConstants'

const styles = (Colors) => StyleSheet.create({

    flatListContainer: {
        flex:1,
        paddingHorizontal: Metrics.width * 0.05
    },
    characterButton:{ 
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors[colorNames.home.buttonBackground],
        marginTop: Metrics.width / 24,
        borderWidth: Metrics.width / 72,
        borderRadius: Metrics.width / 20,
        borderColor: Colors[colorNames.home.buttonBorder]
    },
    characterNameText:{ 
        color: Colors[colorNames.home.episodeText],
        fontSize: Fonts.size(18),
        fontFamily: Fonts.type.bold,
        marginHorizontal: Metrics.width * 0.05,
        marginTop: Metrics.width / 36,
        marginBottom: Metrics.width / 30
    },
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: What's your styles.flatListContainer ?

Comment: I edited the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing your `charactersList` on every iteration. You must do like this

```
    // function that pulls character details from api based on given id
    const takeCharacters = (id) => {
        Axios.get('character/' + id)
            .then(response => {
                let characterDetail = response.data
                setCharacterList(previousState => [...previousState,...characterDetail])
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

You got it? Please, if this code does not correct your problem, provide some prints of your screen.

Comment: I got it! With this code "setCharacterList(characterList => [...characterList,characterDetail]" it worked. Thank you so much! Do you have any suggestions for solve this: " Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, '1'. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version. " This warning start after I wrote codes as you say.

Comment: The FlatList has a prop called ```key``` which was made to make every item your render in it, unique. Take a look at this prop in the following link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist